# ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I tried the below query but I am getting the error  like the tablespace error.
Also i am increased the tablespace to maximum.
but the query is running as expected in my test instance since it is not working in Prod.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p1.emp_id,
    p1.first_name,
    p1.last_name,
    u1.username,
    u1.system_id
FROM
    person p1
    JOIN username_person ap1 ON p1.person_id    = ap1.person_id
    JOIN username u1         ON ap1.username_id = u1.username_id
    JOIN (
        SELECT
           p.domain_id,
            SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN(
                        u.username NOT LIKE 'a-%'
                        AND u.status = 'ACTIVE'
                        AND system_id = 349
                    ) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) AS not_eligible
        FROM
            person p
            JOIN username_person ap ON p.person_id = ap.person_id
            JOIN username u ON ap.username_id = u.username_id
        GROUP BY
            p.emp_id
    ) a ON p1.emp_id = a.emp_id
           AND a.not_eligible = 0
           AND u1.system_id = 123
           AND u1.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

please find the below error :

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.
```

Is there any other way to use the query to avoid the above error?

Comment: You need to show the explain plan - more than likely it is choosing an awful plan which is resulting in the very high temp space usage. Please add the details of the schema, indexes, and the explain plan it generates,

Comment: I think the required action is quite clear: Increase size of TEMP tablespace.

Comment: I have increased the size but it didn't work out

Comment: From what I can tell, the query shouldn't run because `A` has no column called `emp_ID`.

Comment: sry that was a mistake it is also a emp_id

Comment: Three things: 1. The inner query is missing a group-by. 2.As others have said, share the execution plan. 3. How much temp have you allocated? You say the max, but do you really have 32TB of temp (assuming default 8k block size)?